# Free (Or Cheap) Alternatives For An SSL Certificate For Facebook Apps

Tags: facebook, security-certificate, facebook-application

In October (from what I remember) Facebook will require HTTPS connections to pages and app's that are hosted away from Facebook. At the moment, it comes up with a popup saying "do you want to turn secure browsing off". I think (as far as I know) that once October comes people won't be able to access these pages any more.

Now, I know you have to pay for good SSL certificates. However, for a lot of clients this is just going to be a Facebook page, and not mission critical to their businesses. With this in mind, they may not want to pay for an SSL certificate.

I was wondering if there are any free SSL certificates that could do the job? Even if there are no free ones, are there any cheap alternatives?

Also, if you do use a free certificate, will it still work in the same way as a paid for certificate?

Comment: This question on security.stackoverflow.com explains why some certificates are cheap and some are expensive: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-kinds-of-ssl-certificates-are-usable-for-encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has teamed up with Heroku to offer free app hosting including SSL. http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/558/

(Also, don't forget there's a dedicated facebook site: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com.)

Answer (score 3):

StartSSL gives away class 1 certificates for free.

http://www.startssl.com/

Answer (score 1):

A $8.95 per year PositiveSSL should make it

https://www.namecheap.com/ssl-certificates/

AFAIK self signed "free" certificates are not validated by browsers (broken lock with warnings to user)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what class type you want on certificate. Class 1 SSL are sufficient for the facebook pages unless you're redirecting readers or users to some password protected pages. Most of the facebook fan pages can work with class 1 SSL certificates just fine. Startssl.com offers both free and cheap SSL certificates. It is much cheaper than most of the SSL certificate prices in the market.